# how to add a current date, place and signature to the cv

Tags: moderncv, datetime

I am using the template from here
https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv/moderncv-classic/

I wanted texworks to add the latest date and also place and signature(.jpg item) everytime I typeset my cv at the end just before end document. How should I do this?

Comment: If you don't have any problem, can you show me (us) your CV?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just write it out before `\end{document}`, like in any other document type :)
You can use `\today` for the date, and `\includegraphics` to include your `.jpg`.

Answer (score 2):

For the date, you can use a tikzpicture environment if you want to put it as a footer in the last page of the CV as follows

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \node[anchor=south, yshift=0.25cm] at (current page.south) {\textit{Last update: \today}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

For the signature, stick to Xavier's answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your *document* environment, you can incorporate the following code:

```
\emptysection{}\closesection
\vfill
\begin{center}
\textit{\small\today}
\end{center}
```

Furthermore, you can also include your *signature.jpg* using the `\includegraphics` command.